# How to change the subject info of Gmail into Chinese character?

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I got a string  `=?GB2312?B?zbO8xtGnu/m0ocq10bXP7sS/?=` with `$overview[0]->subject;`  in `imap_fetch_overview`  function .

How to change the subject info of Gmail into Chinese character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is a [MIME RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) encoded word which can be decoded using PHP's [`mb_decode_mimeheader`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-decode-mimeheader.php) and [`mb_internal_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) functions.

To convert your MIME encoded string to UTF-8, you can use the following code:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
echo mb_decode_mimeheader('=?GB2312?B?zbO8xtGnu/m0ocq10bXP7sS/?=');
# result: 统计学基础实训项目
```

Comment: would you mind solving the related problem for me?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884890/why-cant-insert-my-subject-of-gmail-header-info-into-a-sqlite3-database